# Why must there be so many delays in Visual Studio 2010 when working with Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, performance

What I mean is I will be editing a .cs file then when I switch over to a .xaml Design mode I must wait for 5 seconds.. and when I switch to another screen its another 3 or 4 seconds...

I understand that compiling will always take time but why can't they cache better to anticipate screen changes ? All this delays add up and I can't get into a zone with all the delays (I am using i7/8 gigs btw)

All my php friends laugh at me!

Comment: You are sitting 3 feet from the problem.  Very hard to guess from the other end of an intertube why your machine is so slow.  Disable your malware scanner, as a start.

Comment: You have SP1 installed, right?

Comment: In such case contact MS support. We can hardly help you with slow performance on your computer.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the design surface or do you just want to edit the XAML? If you just want to edit the XAML, you can right-click on the XAML file in the Solution Explorer and select "Open With...". In the dialog that appears, select "Source Code (Text) Editor" and click the "Set as Default" button. Then click OK. Now your XAML files will all open in the source code editor, which comes up much quicker, and it still gives you intellisense while editing.